# For $T: \mathbb{R^3}\to \mathbb{R^3}$, $\exists$ line $L$ such that $T(L)=L$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, proof-verification, linear-transformations

$T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R^3}$ be a linear transformation. Show that there is a line $L$ such that $T(L)=L$

$\mathbf{Attempt:}$ We represent the linear transformation $T$ with respect to the ordered basis $((1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)) \equiv (e_1,e_2,e_3)$  [We take this particular ordered basis for both the domain and the range space].

The transformation in matrix form be $\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\y_2\\y_3 \end{pmatrix}=A\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}$.

i.e. $T(x_1e_1+x_2e_2+x_3e_3)=y_1e_1+y_2e_2+y_3e_3$.

Now, $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix. Thereby, its characteristic polynomial is of degree $3$, which in turn implies that it has at least one real root, say $\lambda$. Therefore, we can get an eigenvector $\begin{pmatrix} x'_1 \\ x'_2 \\ x'_3 \end{pmatrix}$ corresponding to $\lambda$.

So, $\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\y_2\\y_3 \end{pmatrix}=A\begin{pmatrix} x'_1 \\ x'_2 \\ x'_3 \end{pmatrix}=\lambda \begin{pmatrix} x'_1 \\ x'_2 \\ x'_3 \end{pmatrix} \implies y_i=\lambda x_i $

Now, consider the straight line $\displaystyle\frac{x}{x'_1}=\frac{y}{x'_2}=\frac{z}{x_3'}$. The set of all points on the straight line is $L=\{c(x'_1,x_2',x_3'): c\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Evidently, from the above discussion $T(c(x'_1,x_2',x_3'))=c\lambda (x'_1,x_2',x_3')$.

Therefore, $T(L)\subset L$.

However, I cannot prove the opposite inclusion, i.e. $L \subset T(L)$, because of the trouble arising with $\lambda=0$.

Had it been mentioned that $rank(T)=3$ , there wouldn't be any problem.

But, in case of the matrix with the characteristic equation, $x(x^2+1)=0$, $L \not\subset T(L)$. So the equality fails.

Is the write-up correct? Kindly verify.

Comment: The result is false if you don't assume that $T$ is invertible. A counterexample is when $T$ is the zero map.

Comment: @Crostul This is what I am also getting. Anyway, if you could go through my writing and suggest some improvements, it would of great help.

Comment: What you've said so far (and the claim that $T(L) \subset L$) both seem sound.

Comment: @JohnHughes Thank you for taking a look :)

Comment: I think your write-up is maybe over complicated - as you’ve noticed, the characteristic polynomial has a real root $\lambda$ and hence an eigenvector so that $Tv = \lambda v$. The operator $T$ acts on the line $L = \mathbb{R}v$ as a scaling by $\lambda$, which is invertible iff $\lambda \neq 0$.

Comment: @Joppy Yes, indeed the proof can be shortened a lot. But, being very new to this topic, I have tried to make this proof as detailed as possible, without any shortcuts. I have done this to make sure that I really understand the underlying concepts involved. Next time when I do the proof, it won't be as lengthy :)